# For every closed surface, the set of forbidden topological minors is finite.

Tags: graph-theory, closed-graph, graph-minors, forbidden-subgraphs

I want to prove that for every closed surface, the set of forbidden topological minors is finite.

An idea how to do it is: by starting with the set of forbidden minors. For each forbidden minor $H$, find a finite number of graphs  so that every graph with an minor $H$ contains a subdivision of (at least) one of them.

Is there another easier way how to prove it?

Comment: Your question mentions surfaces on one side and graphs on the other side. Do you mean that you study graphs embedded into a certain surface ? Besides, please, give also a reference to what you call a minor of a graph...

Comment: @JeanMarie The terminology in this question is all very standard and acceptable IMO. 

Anita, what you are looking for is a specialization of the Graph-Minor Theorem of Robertson and Seymour. This is a very long and arduous proof from first principles. You can read up on it here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robertson%E2%80%93Seymour_theorem#Examples_of_minor-closed_families

Comment: All right but why no mention of surfaces in the keywords ?